# Overflow evaluating the requirement `_: Sized` when trying to use Diesel queries

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I'm trying to loosely implement the repository pattern for an application I'm building, however I seem to have hit on some kind of recursive type definition by accident.

On the following code:

```rust
use diesel::{pg::Pg, Insertable, Queryable, QueryDsl, PgConnection, Identifiable, Table};
use std::marker::PhantomData;
use anyhow::anyhow;

pub struct Repository<Entity, SqlType, Tab> {
    _entity_phantom: PhantomData<Entity>,
    _type_phantom: PhantomData<SqlType>,
    table: Tab,
}

impl <Entity, SqlType, Tab> Repository<Entity, SqlType, Tab>
where
    Entity: Queryable<SqlType, Pg> + Insertable<Tab> + Identifiable,
    Tab: Table
{
    fn find_by_id(&self, id: i64, conn: &PgConnection) -> anyhow::Result<Entity> {
        match self.table.find(id).first::<Entity>(conn) {
            Ok(entity) => Ok(entity),
            Err(e) => Err(anyhow!("{}", e)),
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
error[E0275]: overflow evaluating the requirement `_: Sized`
  --> support/src/lib.rs:18:26
   |
18 |         match self.table.find(id).first::<Entity>(conn) {
   |                          ^^^^
   |
   = help: consider adding a `#![recursion_limit="256"]` attribute to your crate (`support`)
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `FilterDsl<_>` for `<Tab as AsQuery>::Query`
```

I've tried increasing the recursion limit at the top of the crate, but to no avail. Sprinking `+ Sized` all over the trait bounds, doesn't seem to do anything as well.

What am I missing?

Comment: hi do you have a solution for insert and update. what is the trait for          diesel::insert_into(self.table)
            .values(data)
            .get_result::<Self::Entity>(self.conn)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Errors like these usually mean that `diesel` could not resolve your trait bounds, due to not being restrictive enough.

Diesel generic programming is usually a bit more complex, but here's a few tips to help you the next time you get this error:

- Whenever you use want to use a specific method like `find`, you have to make sure you **also** check for the same bounds!
- Prefer to build specific re-usable pieces of functions that will allow you to get what you want
- Every time you call a diesel method you are 'wrapping' a new statement, this new statement *has to be bound* or you will get weird error messages like in your question.
- The result of these methods usually have a shorthand like `Find` or `Limit` in code below
- As you can see on line 27, we have to nest `Limit<Find<..>>`, for every new method you call in the query chain, you will need to specify this.

```rust
use anyhow::anyhow;
use diesel::{
    associations::HasTable,
    dsl::{Find, Limit},
    query_dsl::{
        methods::{FindDsl, LimitDsl},
        LoadQuery,
    },
    PgConnection, RunQueryDsl, Table,
};
use std::marker::PhantomData;

pub struct Repository<Entity, Tab> {
    _entity_phantom: PhantomData<Entity>,
    _table_phantom: PhantomData<Tab>,
}

impl<Entity, Tab> Repository<Entity, Tab>
where
    Entity: HasTable<Table = Tab>,
    Tab: Table,
{
    fn find_by_id(&self, id: i64, conn: &PgConnection) -> anyhow::Result<Entity>
    where
        Tab: LimitDsl + FindDsl<i64>,
        Find<Tab, i64>: LimitDsl + Table,
        Limit<Find<Tab, i64>>: LoadQuery<PgConnection, Entity>,
    {
        match Entity::table().find(id).first::<Entity>(conn) {
            Ok(entity) => Ok(entity),
            Err(e) => Err(anyhow!("{}", e)),
        }
    }
}
```

> What am I missing?

Generally one could guess what you were attempting to do, and I do not think it is your fault that you didn't arrive at the expected outcome. This kind of generic programming is hard to understand, and with all the types and their names `T`, `U` it is easy to get lost.

- Your trait bound on `Entity` was wrong if I understood correctly what `Entity` refers to:

  - `Queryable<Query, Database>` is meant to signal that the type it is implemented on can be queried in `Database` through `Query`. It does not make sense to 'pass in' the type `SqlQuery` if you don't pass in the concrete type either!
- `Insertable<Tab>` is, I assume, a left-over from other methods?
- `Identifiable` as well?

Comment: What an amazingly insightful answer, thanks a bunch! :D